# Intentionally force android to wait AND load something in background

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I want to force android to wait AND continue processing something at the same time. I have seen the Thread wait function, but that just makes things hang for a while not actually letting the app do anything. Subsequent processes are simply queued up waiting their turn.

I want to force the timing of a process. This is kind of a combination between having a thread with a wait AND an asynctask

insight appreciated

Comment: more explanation please?

Comment: i dont want to misunderstand again

Comment: Like a loading screen?  That's a combo of a non blocked event thread with some image + and async thread loading in the background.

Comment: Does not compute ... you "want to force android to wait" coupled with "AND continue processing something at the same time". Do you mean spawn another thread and do something else while the main thread waits maybe?

Comment: @sqrfv there is a delay in how the webviews load something, I want to force the app to wait so that the user experience seems normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity{
final WebView yourWebview; //this is the webview
Context mContext = this;

public void onCreate(Bundle B){
setContentView(R.id.somethingtoshow);//this will be shown while webview working

Runnable yourRun = new Runnable(){
public void run(){
yourWebview = new WebView(mContext);
//do whatever you want with it
//loadUrl and whatever you want

//when your done
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
setContentView(yourWebView);
}
});

}
};
Thread T= new Thread(yourRun);
T.start();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

'Waiting' means to put the thread in a suspended state - do you mean having the app simply do nothing until the process is completed?

You never want to make the main event thread hang or wait, that will make the user think the app is frozen.  To do what you are wanting, you will probably spawn an async thread that loads the page from the main activity.  The activity will continue to display whatever you had it doing last, and will not hang up or freeze while the async is going in the background.  However, the user will still be able to press buttons, and might mess you up.

So to get the app to appear unfrozen and allow a process to occur in the background, you will want to enter into some loading screen or limit the user's options on the main layout.  This will allow activity to continue occurring but allow the user a smooth experience.